# How do I get user input from input area with Java Script and assign to a variable?

Tags: javascript, input

I'm trying to make a simple mad libs type game. To do so I need to do the following:

1. Have space that user can input text
2. Retrieve text that user inputted
3. Assign text to variables using Javascript
4. Place variables in Mad libs

I know how to do this using something like:

```
var userAnswer = prompt("Give me an answer");
```

However, I want to get the input from a text input field. I was trying to do the following but I got stuck:

1. Have input area with id="input1"
2. Create function that takes content of #input1 and assign to a variable.
3. Use button to run the function

I will then later use these variables in my story

```
<label for='input1'>Verb + ing</label><input id='input1'>

<script>
    var setInputs = function() {
        var space1 = document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML;
    }
</script>

<button onclick="setInputs">Click me</button>
```

I'm I going about this the correct way?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6rjf5k9n/

Comment: `document.getElementById("input1").value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<label for='input1'>Verb + ing</label><input id='input1'>

        <script>
        var setInputs = function() {
            var space1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
            alert(space1);
        }


        </script>
             <button onclick="setInputs()">Click me</button>
```

`.value` gives you the currently-set value of a form element (input, select, textarea), whereas 
`.innerHTML` builds an HTML string based on the DOM nodes the element contains.

Comment: Awesome! I just had to use ".value" and then I just used   document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML = space1;   afterwards.                                                         However, when I call "space1" in my JS console I get "space1 is not defined." It works for me, I was just wondering why it shows as not defined in the console.